# “On the lake” vs. “in the lake”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following sentences makes sense?

> 1. We took the new kayak out **on** the lake as it was a nice day.
> 2. We took the new kayak out **in** the lake as it was a nice day.

Comment: I used to say *"We took the new kayak out **to** the lake as it was a nice day"* - sounds fine to me, that one.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that you swim ***in*** the lake, and sail ***on*** it. The standard meanings of *in* and *on*, reflecting the different physical relationships of swimmers and sailors to water, surely make the choice of preposition obvious.

Answer (score 3):

If it was a good new kayak I'd say "on the lake" is what I would write.

If the kayak was no good and sank right away, you took it out in the lake.

Comment: While funny, I'm pretty sure you must know that "in the lake" is not appropriate for the example unless it was a kayak/submarine!  Don't forget that our primary goal is to answer questions to the best of our ability. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely *on* the lake.

If you're *in* the lake, you're probably swimming, sinking or otherwise submerged. Think of it like floating *on top of* since the emphasis of boating is staying afloat and moving more or less in 2 dimensions, whereas swimming, fishing and playing tend to involve a little more freedom with respect to movement throughout the depth of the water.

Also, I'd go with *since* instead of *as* and reorder the sentence, "Since it was nice out today, we took the new kayak out on the lake." It's not wrong per se, but *as* works better with comparisons, substitutions or as a way of introducing a fact. Using *as* on its own to talk about the setting or a reason has a tendency to over-inflate the register or tone of formality. As for the reordering of the sentence, it just kinda rolls of the tongue better unless you wanna add a pause in the middle and refer back to some prior point in a conversation.

Other options might be:

*We took the kayak out on the lake today, since it was so nice out*.
*Seeing as how it was so nice out today, we took the kayak out on the lake.*

Comment: FWIW, "since" is sometimes criticized when used for non-temporal reference. (Those critics are, of course, wrong, but it's useful to know)

Comment: Yeah, that'd be kinda like avoiding a preposition at the end of a sentence, even though it's more concise to use phrasal verbs than relative clauses. The scenario strikes me as a rather informal situation though so elevating the register might mean fewer kayaking friends.